# Unable to run a java program from another java program

Tags: java

Iam trying to run a java file(editor.java) from another java program(exec.java). It takes input and displays file not found message.please give me suggestion through which I run a progam succesfully.

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class exec {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
    try {
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);

    System.out.println("Enter the java class name");
    String s=br.readLine();
    String[] cmd = {"java", "-cp", "E:\netbeans\Project\src", s};
    Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()))) {
        String line=null;
        while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        }
        } catch(Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
   }
 }


java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "editor.java": CreateProcess error=2, The system   cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
at project.exec.main(exec.java:18)
```

Comment: Are you passing `editor.java` as commadline argument?

Comment: yes iam passing editor.java as a Commandline argument

Comment: You need to pass a class file. You can't run a .java file with java command right?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass your `.class file` in your command line argument. You don't run a `.java` file with a `java` command.

Just pass `editor` as argument, if the class containing your `main method` is `editor.class`.

Also, do follow the `@Azodious's` answer below.

Also, you might need to change the path in your `array` to the path containing the `class file`. `src` folder might not be having your `class file`

So, run your program using: - `java exec editor`. I think that should work.

Comment: @user1758401. First of all check where is your class file that you want to run. Then copy the path till the folder containing that class file in your code, in the `cmd` array you have made. Now, run your above code using the command: - `java exec editor`. Where I assume that `editor` is the name of your `class` containing the `main` method. You can change that name with the corresponding `class file name`.

Comment: @user1758401. Also, check that your `classpath` contains the path till the folder containing your `class` file.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing commands array to `exec` method

Change it to following:

```
Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

and, your error shows that you are trying to run src file:

```
Cannot run program "editor.java"
```

You should pass the `.class file name` to run it.

Comment: try using only: E:\netbeans\Project

Answer (score 0):

inside **E:\netbeans\Project\src** you found only source file, source file u could not run,,,

try to do in class file found inside ***E:\netbeans\project\build\classes***

```
String[] cmd = {"class", "-cp", "E:\netbeans\project\build\classes\", s};
```

**NOTE: Check your class path**

Thank you

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression at project.exec.main

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues -

1. You are trying to run command "editor.java" from command line. Your command array remains unused.
2. Are your compiled classes in the same directory as source? Usually, with eclipse the classes are generated in `bin` folder. You should be doing -

   `String[] cmd = {"java", "-cp", "E:\netbeans\Project\bin", s};`
   `Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);`
3. Is your `editor.java` in the default package? If not, you need to enter fully qualified name when running the command.

I would suggest try running the class from command line, and then form the same command from Java code.