# Java is not recognized as an internal or external command for eclipse but works well from cmd

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running a sw developped under eclipse (in java) from the cmd. It works well. Once I want to run it from

I am adding a runnble java sw (B.jar) to another java program (A). The "call" of the B.jar works well from the cmd and does the job correctly. Once called from the program (A), it gives me the error of the "unrocognized command". I execute the program (A) from eclipse. Have we to configure some additional information in Eclipse? Or maybe have I to execute directly from the distribution of the software (A)

ScreenShot for the execution from cmd:
[image]

Screenshot from the ececution from eclipse:
[image]

> 2020-06-24 12:57:26,172 [Thread-7] INFO  - 'java' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
> 2020-06-24 12:57:26,173 [Thread-7] INFO  - ou externe, un programme ex‚cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
> 2020-06-24 12:57:36,141 [Thread-6] INFO  - Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...

The script from (A) to call (B) :

```
private final InputStream inputStream;

class Flux implements Runnable {

    private final InputStream inputStream;

    Flux(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    private BufferedReader getBufferedReader(InputStream instream) {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));

    }

    public void run() {
        BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(inputStream);
        String line = "";
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

String command =  B_SW_AbsolutePath + " "+ usersCommand;
try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            this.proc = rt.exec(command, {""}, outputDir);
            Trace.info("execution "+command+" "+outputDir.toString());
            
            Flux outputStream = new Flux(
                    this.proc.getInputStream());
            Flux errorStream = new Flux(
                    this.proc.getErrorStream());
            new Thread(outputStream).start();
            new Thread(errorStream).start();
            this.proc.waitFor(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Trace.erreur("External software can not be run " + e.getMessage());
        }
        
        finally{
            
            this.process.destroy(); 
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: maybe a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133482/unable-to-run-a-java-program-from-another-java-program

Comment: @vmrvictor That looks similar, but it is not really the same problem;
in my case, the communication between both programms works well (I guess), the problem is after running from eclipse, I have a java error

Comment: which java error do you have, can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: please do not use screenshots but copy paste the text here

Comment: @vmrvictor java is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a commands file

Comment: How is the call to B done? Using a Runtime.exec() or something? It would be helpful to post the code that does the execution.

Comment: @Gimby
yes, Runtime.exec() is used. ok I'll try to post it

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME environment variable set, and is the JDK/JRE's `bin` folder on your PATH?

Comment: @DustinR yes! and I can execute the program from the cmd

Comment: @Nour if you try to include the full path to the java.exe in your Runtime.exec call, does it work?

Comment: @DustinR you think that it might be the source of the problem? I did the same for another program in the past and it did work. and that full path is what I use from the cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `Runtime.exec(String cmd,String[] envp,File dir)` overload with `{""}` for envp you have provided the child process with no environment variables and particularly no PATH envvar, equivalent to an empty one. Since your batch file apparently runs a simple program name `java` instead of a complete pathname, it needs to be looked up in the PATH variable and since the PATH variable is empty that lookup fails. If you don't want to or can't change the batch file to specify complete paths for everything (and otherwise not depend on any envvars) -- and if necessary similarly change everything it runs -- the best solution is to **pass `null` for the second (envp) argument to `exec`** so it uses the default which is the parent Java's own envvars. The harder method is to construct a list of the correct envvars (with values) manually, and pass that.

Also, instead of concatenating `"script"+" "+"argument"` which `Runtime.exec` must re-split, you can use the `String[]` overload with `new String[]{"script","command"}`. Depending on the compiler you might not need the `new String[]`; I haven't kept track of all the type-deduction changes because I usually prefer to be explicit. But since you want the combination for your tracing, maybe not.